# If $(A + I_n)^m = 0$, show that $A$ is invertible and find $\det(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, characteristic-functions, minimal-polynomials

Assume $(A + I_n)^m = 0$. Prove that $A$ is invertible and find $\det(A)$.

I started by binomial expansion, and set it equal zero. Is that correct? What would be the best approach?

Comment: Yes. The binomial expansion should give you an explicit formula for the inverse of A, thus proving invertability. For the determinant here is a hint: it is equal to the constant term of the characteristic polynomial of A.

Comment: Certainly not true when $n=0$.

Comment: Um, I read $In$ as the scalar multiple more commonly written $nI$. You probably  mean $I_n$ instead; try to learn the MathJax formatting.

Comment: Write $A + I = N$, so that $N^m = 0$, hence $N$ is nilpotent. Then $A = N - I$ is the difference of a nilpotent and invertible matrix, and it's possible to write down very explicitly a formula for the inverse of $A$ (hint: $I - N^m = I$).

Answer (score 2):

The equation says that $A+I_n$ is nilpotent, so it has characteristic polynomial $(X+1)^n$. Setting $X=0$ in it gives $\det(-A)$, which apparently is $1$, so $\det(A)=(-1)^n$ (alternatively, $\det(A)$ is the product of all eigenvalues (counted with their algebraic multiplicity) and here they all are$~{-}1$).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, we can use the binomial expansion (since $A$ commutes with $I_n$) and we get 
$$
0=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom mk A^kI_n^{m-k}=I_n+\sum_{k=1}^m\binom mk A^k
=I_n+A\sum_{k=1}^m\binom mk A^{k-1}
$$
hence we got the equality 
$$
 \left(-\sum_{k=1}^m\binom mk A^{k-1}\right)\cdot A=I_n,
$$
which shows that $A$ is invertible, and its inverse is  $-\sum_{k=1}^m\binom mk A^{k-1}$.